# c Static float error: ‘????’ redeclared as different kind of symbol

Tags: c, static-variables, redefinition

unable to compile a c program, problem with symbol redefinition. Have tried various variable data type definitions, cannot understand what is going on here regarding float and static float. Have given it a good shot, any help appreciated.

Chris

```
$ gcc -Wall -g -O6 -I../include   -c -o edge.o edge.c
```

Error message:

```
problem with edge.c: In function ‘qc_edge’:
edge.c:30:15: error: ‘kernel’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
edge.c:23:77: note: previous definition of ‘kernel’ was here
```

Code fragment with line numbers:

```
18 //qc_edge (q, scan, start, gap, conv_kernel, 3, 3));
19 }
20
21 /******************************************************************/
22
23 scanbuf *qc_edge (struct qcam *q, scanbuf *scan, int start, int gap, float *kernel, int  
kernel_x, int kernel_y)
24 { scanbuf *scantmp;
25  int i;
26  int s, height, width,
27    grad;
28  float deltaX, deltaY;
29
30 static float kernel [3][3] = {{1, 2, 1},
32                    {2, -1, 2},
33                    {1, 2, 1}};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scanbuf *qc_edge (struct qcam *q, scanbuf *scan, int start, int gap, float *kernel, int  
kernel_x, int kernel_y)                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^// pointer to float type

static float kernel [3][3] = {{1, 2, 1},  array of float.  So you cant have one variable with two declaration in same scope. try changing the variable name.
```

Try:

```
24 { scanbuf *scantmp;
25  int i;
26  int s, height, width,
27    grad;
28  float deltaX, deltaY;
29
30 static float kernel_temp [3][3] = {{1, 2, 1},  <---- Change name
32                    {2, -1, 2},
33                    {1, 2, 1}};
```